# Auth to private cloud9 https server with DialogFlow

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, http-authentication, dialogflow-es

I have two cloud 9 with the same nodejs code.
One is the old (public) and I recently moved to a private one. I have updated the URL field inside the fulfillment section but my bot doesn't answer anymore.

I have tried to change the private status to public for the new one and it works... I saw the auth fields, What I have to put there to make my bot working?

Thank you per avance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogflow's webhooks require [a publicly accessible endpoint](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment).  If you've made your server private and inaccessible to the internet Dialogflow cannot communicate with your sever to send webhook requests.